# Unable to Start module mod_last_odbc in ejabberd using mysql

Tags: mysql, erlang, ejabberd

I have configured ejabbered to authenticate users through mysql table, After configuring when I am trying to start the module mod_last_odbc is not starting. Here is the ejabberd.cfg details.

```
{auth_method, odbc}.
{odbc_server, {mysql, "localhost", 3306, "ejabberd", "root", "password"}}.
{access, max_user_sessions, [{10, all}]}.     
{modules,
 [
  {mod_adhoc, []},
  {mod_disco, []},
  {mod_last_odbc, []},
  {mod_stream_management, [
                          ]},
  {mod_muc, [
             {host, "muc.@HOST@"},
             {access, muc},
             {access_create, muc_create}
            ]},
  {mod_muc_log,
        [
        {outdir, "/tmp/muclogs"},
        {access_log, muc}
        ]},
  {mod_offline_odbc, [{access_max_user_messages, max_user_offline_messages}]},
  {mod_privacy_odbc, []},
  {mod_private_odbc, []},
  {mod_register, [
      {welcome_message, {""}},
      {ip_access, [{allow, "127.0.0.0/8"},
             {deny, "0.0.0.0/0"}]},
      {access, register}
     ]},
  {mod_roster_odbc, []},
  {mod_sic, []},
  {mod_vcard_odbc, [ {allow_return_all, true},
{search_all_hosts, true}
]},
  {mod_bosh, []},
  {mod_websockets, []},
  {mod_metrics, []},
  {mod_carboncopy, []}

 ]}.
```

Comment: Do you get any error message?

Answer (score 1):

No need to add _odbc to all module. Just change **auth_method** as **odbc** and then give **odbc_server** details then after it does the work.

Comment: Using odbc with module names was how it was done for ejabberd 2.x. You indeed have now a central odbc parameter.